# Warning Unresponsive script in firefox - What it means and how to fix it

Tags: angularjs, firefox

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: /js/angular.min.js:29022[image]

Comment: You probably have an unending loop somewhere in your code